# Case insensitive directory access in Java on Unix

Tags: java, file, unix, directory, case-sensitive

I am working on Unix, which uses case sensitive filenames and need a way to access them in a case-insensitive manner.

Specifically, at time the program needs to get into a /images directory under a project folder.  But because this directory is created manually by the user, it may sometimes be named Images, IMAGES, iMaGes...you get the idea.

Given that there is guaranteed to be only one images directory in any project folder, how can I access this directly without getting the entire directory list and looping through it?

Comment: what's wrong with looping through the directory list and doing a case insensitive comparision?  Are there that many other folders/files in the directory (especially if you do this once and save what they called it in a config file or something)

Comment: You cna have all three `Images`, `IMAGES`, `iMaGes` at the same time with Unix.  You may need a way to determine which is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no other way then reading the full list of directory names and check each and everyone if it matches your pattern.

You can *hide* it by using a `FilenameFilter` that filters all folder names that don't match your pattern (iaw, any folder, whose lowercased name is equal to `images`). This may be a better approach, because it will return *all* candidates (iaw: `./Images`, `./imaGes`, `./IMAGES` if you have creative users that place more then one image folder ;) )

Answer (score 2):

In Java 7 there is something called a [PathMatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/PathMatcher.html) which allows you to use regular expressions to find a file.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution that doesn't involve looping over *either* the list of entries in the directory *or* the list of possible permutations of lower and upper case letters.

Unix **is** case sensitive and asking for `/image` when only `/Image` exists won't get you a positive answer.

The only exception is when the file system that's used is not case sensitive (for example FAT variants are not case-sensitive), but that only really applies for external media, usually.

Comment: Looping over the possible permutations of lower and upper case letters is a terrible idea. Just convert both sides to lowercase and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a folder the user created, then give them a file chooser UI to select the folder. Either that or, when the project is created, create the images folder too in a way that's predictable later.

Comment: This is indeed how the program works now, but legacy projects I'd like to support unfortunately did not automatically create a guaranteed images folder.